# How to calculate totals in dataframe by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I have got this dataframe:

```
Date Trader1 Trader2 Trader3
01/04/2020  4   6   8
02/04/2020  4   6   8
03/04/2020  4   7   8
04/04/2020  4   7   8
05/04/2020  3   5   7
06/04/2020  2   4   7
07/04/2020  2   3   6
08/04/2020  3   3   6
09/04/2020  3   5   7
10/04/2020  3   5   7
11/04/2020  3   5   6
```

I would like to get Totals for each column by using python/pandas library. When I apply `a.loc['Total'] = pd.Series(a.sum())` I can get result as Totals for each column, but it also adds together values of `Date` column (dates). How can I calculate totals only for needed columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select only numeric columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
a.loc['Total'] = a.select_dtypes(np.number).sum()
```

You can remove column `Date` by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
a.loc['Total'] = a.drop('Date', axis=1).sum()
```

Or select all columns without first by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
a.loc['Total'] = a.iloc[:, 1:].sum()
```

---

```
print (a)
             Date  Trader1  Trader2  Trader3
0      01/04/2020      4.0      6.0      8.0
1      02/04/2020      4.0      6.0      8.0
2      03/04/2020      4.0      7.0      8.0
3      04/04/2020      4.0      7.0      8.0
4      05/04/2020      3.0      5.0      7.0
5      06/04/2020      2.0      4.0      7.0
6      07/04/2020      2.0      3.0      6.0
7      08/04/2020      3.0      3.0      6.0
8      09/04/2020      3.0      5.0      7.0
9      10/04/2020      3.0      5.0      7.0
10     11/04/2020      3.0      5.0      6.0
Total         NaN     35.0     56.0     78.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data[['Trader1','Trader2','Trader3']].sum()
```

I just saw your comment, There may be better ways, but  I think this should work

```
data[data.columns[1:]].sum()
```

you have to provide the range in last line.

Comment: You can pass the columns whose totals you want to calculate as above.

Comment: How to modify this if I will have not known number or "Trader" columns and I do not know exact names?

Something like `data[[1:]].sum()` will work?

Comment: also last part of the answer by @jezrael  **a.loc['Total'] = a.iloc[:, 1:].sum()**  , does precisely the thing you want.